# Why is my objects turn into arrays after pushing object into another array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

JS newbie here.  I'm learning to convert a nested array into an array containing objects.

My question: Why does `var outObj = {};` turns into an array after pushing `outobj{}` into `outArr[]`?
(Please see expected and actual output at the end of this post)  Thank you in advance for your help.

```
function transformEmployeeData(inArr) {
  var outArr = []; 

  for(var x = 0; x < inArr.length; x++){

    var outObj = {}; // The obj that will be stores in outArr[]
    var a1 = inArr[x]; 
    //console.log(a1 + '\n');

    for(var y = 0; y < a1.length; y++){
      outObj[a1[y][0]] = a1[y][1];
      //console.log(outObj[a1[y][0]]);
    }
    outArr.push(outObj);
  }
  return arr;
}

var arr = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
    ]
];
console.log(transformEmployeeData(arr)); 
/* 
Expected Output:
[
    {firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk'},
    {firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager'}
]

Actual Output:
[ [ [ 'firstName', 'Joe' ],
    [ 'lastName', 'Blow' ],
    [ 'age', 42 ],
    [ 'role', 'clerk' ] ],
  [ [ 'firstName', 'Mary' ],
    [ 'lastName', 'Jenkins' ],
    [ 'age', 36 ],
    [ 'role', 'manager' ] ] ]
*/
```

Comment: You are returning the value you are passing to the function (indirectly). Do `console.log(transformEmployeeData([]));` and be surprised ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `outArr` instead of `arr` from `transformEmployeeData()` function call

```
return outArr;
```

Comment: Phew....thanks so much @guest271314   Learning everything and sorting out everything at once made my mind tired.